# JSON how to ignore missing object during deserialization

Tags: c#, json

I have a sample JSON that when i deserialize i get "object reference not set to instance of an object" because i found out some that sometimes the field is missing then it will reappear again.

the json is similar to this

```
{
    "title": "Example",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "firstName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "lastName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "age": {
            "description": "Age in years",
            "type": "integer",
            "minimum": 0
        }
    }

}
```

if i deserialize this and map it to the corresponding fields the result is OK

but if for example the "Age" is missing

```
{
    "title": "Example",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "firstName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "lastName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
    },
    "required": ["firstName", "lastName"]
}
```

it will throw an error "object reference not set to instance of an object"
how do i ignore the age if it's missing in JSON?

Comment: What library do you use?

Comment: if its real POCO object I check if this any property there with null, I assigned then with blank object. like `if(MyObject.Properties.Age==null) { MyObject.Properties.Age = new Age();}`  then deserialize it.

Comment: i use json.net library

Comment: The "Age" should be null in your case. What is your lib version? V6.0.8 works in a similar case.

Comment: i tried adding new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore}); at the end of deserialization it still throws an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

**Update**
when you said you using json.net

I will say there is setting for Json.net try the below

```
JsonSerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
```

---

if its real POCO object,  I check if any property there with null, I assigned then with blank object.
like

```
if(MyObject.Properties.Age==null)
{
   MyObject.Properties.Age = new Age();
}
```

then deserialize it.

Comment: do i add this on my class?

Comment: [JsonProperty("age", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]

Comment: yes... you can add either way.. i mean either add as attribute on property of 'AGE' or whatever it is.. or you can set the centralize for all using  JsonSerializerSetting static class.