# How to ignore empty or not setted json key?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a json like this:

```
{
"user": [
{
  "det": [
    {
      "Code": "9",
      "Description": "Update"
    }
  ],
  "arts": []
 }
]
}
```

Now in some case the json that I reiceve contains the key `arts` in other case this key isn't provided, so simply I have only the json with the `det` key as:

```
{
"user": [
{
  "det": [
    {
      "Code": "9",
      "Description": "Update"
    }
  ]
 }
]
}
```

and this is my class for deserializing it:

```
public class Det
{
   public string Code { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Arts
{
   public string ID { get; set; }
   public string CON3 { get; set; }
}

public class user
{
   public List<Det> det { get; set; }
   public List<Arts> arts {get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Det> user { get; set; }
}
```

So when I receive the first json the code working well, but when I receive the second the code fall in exception:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object

This because the `arts` key isn't provided but there is only the `det` key. So there is a way to tell to my code to ignore `arts` if is not setted? How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: What are you using to deserialize? Using google, I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578846/ignore-missing-properties-during-jackson-json-deserialize-in-java) if you are using "`Jackson`", and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30928903/json-how-to-ignore-missing-object-during-deserialization) for "`Json.net`".

Comment: @Quantic I'm using `Json.net` I'll take a look to the seconds link.

Comment: Ok I modified the second link to a more relevant one, so double check it in case you checked before I changed it.

Comment: @Quantic I tried to put this property: `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.AllowNull)]` above this line: `public List<Arts> arts {get; set; }` but still get the same error. It's not possible manage it directly in the class declaration?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to deserialize? I just tried `var test1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<user>(json2);` and it works fine. In this case `json2` is a string that is a copy if your second json code you posted.

Comment: @Quantic My bad. I tried with: `JsonProperty("arts", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]` and the deserialization seems working. Thanks for the help, I have appreciated. Just one question: when I execute (in my foreach) this condition ` if (det.arts.Count > 0)` I get: `NullReferenceException` this 'cause `arts` is null, how can I prevent this situation?

Comment: @Sandokan - check [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).  Simplest thing to do is to check for null.

Comment: yeah I execute the check but still get the error maybe I'll open a new question.

Comment: @Sandokan - you have a bug in your `RootObject` class.  It should be `public List<user> user { get; set; }` not `public List<Det> user { get; set; }`.

Comment: Yes, @dbc I noticed it. Anyway for the related value `null` I opened a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36457413/cant-check-if-a-specific-object-key-is-null