# Can't check if a specific object key is null

Tags: c#

I have this object:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseText);
```

now in some case the deserialization generate two key: `arts` and `det`. The `det` key is even filled, but in some cases the key `arts` could be null. I check the object content `null` like this:

```
foreach(var item in obj.det){
   ...
   if(!item.arts.Equal(null)){ 'the problem is here
    ...
   }
}
```

The problem is on the condition, in particular I check if the `arts` key is different against `null` but I got this exception:

> NullReference Exception was not managed

I don't understand what I did wrong, could someone enlight me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Silvermind I already checked it, and there is a suggestion to use `Equals`.

Comment: Your statement in your comment is incorrect. Check the examples that specify the correct implementation. You should use operators like `==` for `null` comparison.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
if(item.arts == null){
 // do your checking operation
}
```

I am not sure if that is causing your problem but in general calling a method on a null object creates an error.

Comment: @nhouser9 Yes, seems working good thanks. So I guess that `Equals` method not working in this case if the object is null.

Comment: @Sandokan No problem. In general, if an object is null you can't call one of its methods. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as a solution =)